# Mixing repositories in tortoise

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Will tortoise let me mix repositories in the same and if so how? What I would like is to store code, configs and binaries in separate repositories.

Comment: While Lasse has shown you how to do this, I would re-consider this. I'd use externals only for code that's shared among different repositories. If you configs and binaries (Why binaries, BTW? If they can be re-created from the source, don't check them in!) belong to these and only these sources, why not put them together? What does it gain you?

Comment: The reason is I want to script my production server to pick up fresh binaries every day. I'm trying to plug the security holes this leaves and I'm sure there's a good ftp-solution there aswell. I'll have SSL soon aswell, but for the time being, this seemed like a nice solution. I do have different repositories for this. The repository for the production binaries are actually on the production server, allowing me to have different user and firewall settings. Also branching and tagging I hope will allow me to have different production, testing and development versions. cont...

Comment: ... I haven't thought this out 100% as you can see. It's an interesting discussion. Perhaps I'll start a new thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should look at externals, using the `svn:externals` property, this will allow you to have one repository, with external references to other repositories.

For instance, you can do this:

```
trunk/                         <-- repository A
   config/                     <-- repository B
   binaries/                   <-- repository C
   code/                       <-- repository A
```

You cannot, however, mix files from different repositories in one working copy, but you can use externals to check out sub-directories of your working copy from different repositories.

For more information about externals, check the svnbook: [Externals Definitions](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch07s04.html).

Answer (score 3):

Subversion allows almost all sort of mixed working copies. You can combine different revisions, different locations within the repository and even different repositories.

The feature you mention is accomplished with *externals*:

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.externals.html

However, these mixed working copies that combine different sources can be difficult to deal with. When you make changes you have to remember this fact and do a different checkout for each source. And you cannot merge stuff between different repositories so you won't have a proper history.

Honestly, I see little reason to split one single project into three different repos.

Comment: You're conclusion is noted. After trying it out, it works, but let it be known it's probably not worth it. In my case it's for security reasons but there is proably a better way.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean whether one checkout can include stuff from multiple repositories, then no. You should use one repository with subfolders for code, configs and binaries.